# SQLite matching column name , ignoring commas

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, ormlite

I've got a database with several columns and a column `name` and I'm doing the following sqlite statement through OrmLite:

```
SELECT `name`,`id`,`ita_name`,`setCode`
FROM `MyTable`
WHERE (`name` LIKE ?)
ORDER BY `name` LIMIT 30
```

everything works fine but if the value of the `name` column  is "Michael*,* Basketball player"  and I submit "Michael Basketball player" the query return no results.
I've already tried to use %myQueryText% but with no success.
What can i do to return values from my column ignoring "," ?

Answer (score 2):

SQL `LIKE` statement is more specific, than you think. The `%` wildcard matches zero or more characters *at the position of the wildcard*, so `%myQueryText%` matches *anythingmyQueryText* OR *myQueryTextanything* but not *myQuery(comma)text*. You need place wildcard at position of comma, see [SQL LIKE wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

So you probably want something like

```
... WHERE (`name` LIKE "Michael%Basketball player") ...
```

Edit/ Prepare your search pattern in Java, possibly like

```
String searchPattern = "Michael Basket player";
String preparedPattern = searchPattern.replace(' ', '%');
// outputs pattern "Michael%Basket%player"
```

Which could match even **Michael the best Basketbal and other sports player** and if you want to overcome such troubles, you can use [`REGEXP`](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2013/05/24/REGEXP-operator-for-SQLite3) and prepare search pattern:

```
String searchPattern = "Michael Basket player";
String preparedPattern = searchPattern.replace(' ', '[,\s]+');
// outputs pattern "Michael[,\s]+Basket[,\s]+player"
```

and then in SQL query change `WHERE` statement to

```
WHERE `name` REGEXP "Michael[,\s]+Basket[,\s]+player"
```

the `[,\s]+` matches either comma or white space and the occurance is one or multiple times, so it matches one space or space and comma or comma and more spaces...

Comment: Thanks for your response, i was aware of this behaviour but my column values have differrent names:
Eg:
Jane, some text
Alexander, other text
So i think that the wildcard approach could be problematic. The only thing that values of the column have in common is that there's always a space after "," .
the situation is: [variable length text],[variable length text] maybe i didn't explained cleary in my question :)

Comment: Comma is no problem for SQL `LIKE` statement. If you're sure the search pattern is good, then the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: well in fact the query works fine, but i'd like to search for "Michael Basket player" and return the value from the column whose has "Michael, Basket player". If i write comma in my query i'm able to retrieve my desired result, but if don't  i'm not, because sql consider comma as a char to match.